# Xuggler get jpeg image from rtsp stream

Tags: java, stream, jpeg, rtsp, xuggler

What i must use here, to save jpeg image?

```
            String[] args = new String[] { "--containerformat", "jpeg", "--acodec",
            "libmp3lame", "--asamplerate", "22050", "--achannels", "1",
            "--abitrate", "64000", "--aquality", "0", "--vcodec", "jpegls",
            "--vscalefactor", "1.0", "--vbitrate", "300000",
            "--vbitratetolerance", "12000000", "--vquality",
            "0",
            "--realtime", // this will stream out to an RTMP server
            url,
            "com.xuggle.xuggler.RTMPPublishingExhaustiveTest#testRTSPRead.jpeg" };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java is very hard to connect to rtsp and make screenshot, I changed language of my program to c#, and I used vlc api, this api isn't very good to make screenshot to bitmap(it save screenshot to file), but it's some way.

Comment: is any other way to get image from RTSP image